# On provability in modal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic, kripke-models

Consider the classical modal logic $\mathsf K$, given by the following axioms and rules over a language containing the standard propositional connectives and $\Box$:

- A complete set of axiom schemes for classical propositional logic
- $\Box(\phi\rightarrow\psi)\rightarrow(\Box\phi\rightarrow\Box\psi)$
- From $\phi$ and $\phi\rightarrow\psi$, infer $\psi$
- From $\vdash\phi$, infer $\vdash\Box\phi$

The formulation of the necessitation rule shall mean that it should only be applied to theorems (to allow derivations from premises) where $\vdash$ denotes provability in $\mathsf K$.

It is well known that $\mathsf K$ is complete with respect to its classical Kripke semantics.

What I am interested in is the following metatheorem:

$$\text{If }\vdash\Box\phi\text{, then }\vdash\phi$$

It is the converse to the necessitation rule and a weakening of the principle $\Box\phi\rightarrow\phi$ (of course only valid in reflexive models) to theorems of the logic.

By appealing to the completeness theorem, it is obvious that it is valid, by assuming $\not\vdash\phi$, i.e. there is a countermodel for $\phi$ and transforming this into a countermodel of $\Box\phi$.

This means that the rule is admissible in $\mathsf K$. My question is if there is a proof of the metatheorem which just appeal to the proof system $\mathsf K$ and not to any semantic issue.

Comment: Maybe this is overkill, but this follows from cut elimination in a sequent calculus presentation of $K$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen i was looking for something more simple, but this is very nice and at least something.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Maybe you could elaborate a little more on how it follows from cut elimination.

Comment: You would devise a cut-free sequent calculus such that $\vdash\phi$ in the Hilbert system if and only if the sequent $ \Rightarrow\phi$ is provable in the sequent calculus. It being cut-free would guarantee that the only way one could deduce $\Rightarrow \square \phi$ as the endsequent would be to use the inference $$ \dfrac{\Rightarrow \phi}{\Rightarrow \square\phi}$$ (I hesitate to write down the general form of the right rule for $\square$ for fear of getting it wrong, since the kinds of side formulas that can appear would be restricted, in accord with some remarks in your question.)

Comment: I wish I knew a good reference to point to here. The best I see offhand is that in Troelstra and Schwictenberg they sketch a cut elimination for a sequent calculus for S4. They give both the devising of the calculus and the proof of cut elimination for K as an exercise.